# My player is switching between animations when it is not programed to

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

When my player is moving, the animation switches between idle and walk when I am holding down D. I played the animation and it looks fine but when I play the transition it starts idle and switches to walk. I have tried creating a new project and doing it again but it does the same thing. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    float moveForce = 10f;

    [SerializeField]
    float jumpForce = 11f;

    float movementX;

    Rigidbody2D myBody;

    Animator Anim;

    private SpriteRenderer sr;

    string WALK_ANIMATION = "Walk";

    private void Update()
    {
        playerMoveKeyboard();
        animatePlayer();
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        myBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        Anim = myBody.GetComponent<Animator>();
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();



    }
    void playerMoveKeyboard()
    {
        movementX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        transform.position += new Vector3(movementX, 0f, 0f) * moveForce * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    void animatePlayer()
    {
        if(movementX > 0)
        {
            Anim.SetBool(WALK_ANIMATION, true);
            sr.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (movementX < 0)
        {
            Anim.SetBool(WALK_ANIMATION, true);
            sr.flipX = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Anim.SetBool(WALK_ANIMATION, false);
        }



    }
}
```

[image: my animation]

[image: Animator Window]

Comment: your problem probably comes from the animator component, can you show the Animator tab so we can help you better ?

Comment: also, don't make comparison this way with floats `movementX == 1`.
the float type has imprecision and this kind of comparison will not be true if movementX is equal to 0.999999... prefer doing something like `movementX > .5f`
more info about float imprecision in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0)

Comment: @cfaz I added the animator window and changed my code

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I am seeing the problem correctly from the gif, but can't you just turn off "Has exit time" and change the transition duration to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but using a float instead of a bool to decide when to play the animation might solve this. That is how I've been doing it and never had any problems.

Do this by creating a new parameter in the animator called "Speed". Change the condition from idle to walk to `Speed greater 0.01` and walk to idle to `Speed less 0.01` or some other small number.

In the code you can change "Speed" to the player speed by adding:

```
anim.setFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(movementX))
```

to the update function inside the player movement script.

You should also remove the `Anim.SetBool()` from  the funciton `animatePlayer()`.